# Google Channel API message from JavaScript client to server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, channel-api

After a while I got the first part of the `Google Channel API` working. Now I have some problems with sending a message from the JavaScript client to the server.
Here is the servlet for the `Google Channel API` connection:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        ChannelService channelService = ChannelServiceFactory.getChannelService();
        String token = channelService.createChannel(user.getUserId());

        FileReader reader = new FileReader("index.html");
        CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.allocate(16384);
        reader.read(buffer);
        reader.close();

        String index = new String(buffer.array());
        index = index.replaceAll("\\{\\{ token \\}\\}", token);

        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        resp.getWriter().write(index);
    } else {
        resp.sendRedirect(userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI()));
    }
```

The `index.html` looks like following:

```
<script src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        onOpened = function() {
            alert("opened");
        }

        var token = "{{ token }}";
        var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);
        var handler = {
            'onopen' : onOpened,
            'onmessage' : onMessage,
            'onerror' : function() {
            },
            'onclose' : function() {
            }
        };
        var socket = channel.open(handler);
        socket.onopen = onOpened;
        socket.onmessage = onMessage;

        function sendMessage() {
            // Send JSON object to server   
        }
    </script>
    <h1>Google Test Channel API</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="sendMessage();">
    </form>
</body>
```

If I load the application I get the `opened` alert, I believe the connection is working. Now I would like to send a message to the server, if someone clicks on the button.

I read that I have to use the XMLHttpRequest function with POST or GET. But I won’t pass a new url, I 
would just pass a value. Is there a way to send a JSON object to the server?

Something like:

```
{
    "message": "This is a JavaClient message!"
}
```

Comment: I am not even to create channel first time. Can you please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332222/unable-to-create-new-channel-in-javascript-of-channel-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really have much to do with the Chanel API - it's just a standard xhr call back to the server. You can use standard code [like this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp), or use a library such as jquery [like this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

If you need to parse javascript into JSON use JSON.stringify().

At the server you can process your request as required, send a response back to the client via standard HTTP or use the Chanel API to send a message not just to the original client, but to all connected clients.

Comment: Yea, but how do I react at the server side? Is the second paramter from `xmlhttp.open` a servlet? In every example they pass a url as paramter, could it also be a JSON object? Greetz.

Comment: it's a link which is mapped to a servlet yeah. you then treat it as any other http request. it's pretty standard stuff i recommend you read this -> https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/rpc. It's python, but the concepts are the same for java

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiair with the channel API blog post of Nick Johnson:

http://blog.notdot.net/2011/07/Using-the-Channel-API-on-App-Engine-for-instant-traffic-analysis

Comment: No I am not, he is using python for the server side code, but I will have a look on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

App Engine's Channel API is pretty much only for sending messages from the server->client.  It's a one way channel.

That's fine because it's not hard to build the client->server channel, but you do have to build it yourself, it's not for free.  You do have to define your own url for the client->server message, then use an XMLHttpRequest to send your message to that url.

There's a small exception in that the Channel API also has a built on mechanism to notify the server of connects/disconnects.  Under the cover, these are done using XMLHttpRequests to predefined urls (I think it's something like _ah/channel/disconnect or something.  These won't be useful to you since they're automatically called - you can't define when they are called, or the content.

So yeah, just implement your own URL handler, and send your JSON data to that URL.