# unable to create new channel in javascript of channel API

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, channel-api

Here is my python file

```
import os
from google.appengine.api import channel
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import logging


token = 'default'

class SendMessage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        logging.info('Sending messgae with tokens : ' + token)
        channel.send_message(token,'Hello from the server')

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        global token
        token = channel.create_channel('ram')
        logging.info('Token : ' + token)
        channel.send_message(token,'Hello from the server')
        template_values = {'token': token}
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')

        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))



application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),('/sendmessage',SendMessage)], debug=True)


def main():
  run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

and HTML file

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/channel.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <script>
            var state = {
                token: '{{ token }}'
            };
            var token = state.token;
            openChannel = function () {
                var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token.toString());
                var socket = channel.open();
                socket.onopen = function () {
                    alert('open');
                };
                socket.onmessage = function () {
                    alert('message');
                };
                socket.onerror = function () {
                    alert('error');
                };
                socket.onclose = function () {
                    alert('close');
                };
            };

            sendMessage = function () {

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', '/sendmessage', true);
                xhr.send();
            };
        </script>
        Hi All, <br>
        <button onclick="openChannel()">Open Connection</button>
        <button onclick="sendMessage()">Send Message</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

On the page there is Open Connection button that create the channel to the created token on server side. Now when I click on this button it flashes the error alert and then close alert. I want to make a channel and send message from server to the browser.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: What's the error? Do you see anything in the JavaScript console?

Comment: it is not showing any error on javascript console :(

Comment: I am running this on my local dev server. any change  i have to make to run on local ?

Comment: You should add an "err" parameter to the onerror function and log it, OP

Comment: Also, "{{ token }}" seems to be out-of-place. What is in charge of actually templating that token? Isn't the serve creating its own token?